# Why to use Application subclass to hold global variables?

Tags: singleton, global-variables, android

In my App I use the public class Globals to hold static variables that I set and get in the whole application simply by referring to them by p.e. Globals.someString:

```
public class Globals {
    // several static variables for use in the whole application:
    static String someString = "";
}
```

My app seems to work fine. But now I read everywhere that global variables should be defined in a subclass of Application or a own singleton class and be accessed by setters and getters.

My question is now: Is there any drawback to my own way to use global variables? Memory leaks p.e. or other issues?

Comment: globals are bad ... anyway, until you do not use Activity/Service instances as global (or class which needs Activity/Service context like Views instance, etc.) then there is no differences between global class and Application subclass ...

Answer (score 2):

two part answer:

**1st part: myths and theories**

In general in Object Orientation the use of static Globals are not advised because it's a pretty uncontrollable. That's where the suggestion to use `Singleton` with getters/setters come from. It's a more controllable manageable environment. But if you're the solely developer of the application and don't mind about it. That's really best practices and not really required for the proper functioning of an app.

subclass `Application` or have your own public class makes no difference if all you're using are Strings, int, etc. It's a common thing around the internet to subclass application if you're initialising objects that needs a Context, for example a database. Personally I don't like that approach too much. It slows-down boot times and might keep big objects that I don't really need in memory. For those types I usually go for lazy-initialisation, where I hold a `public static` reference of my application and whenever I call, for example, `MyDatabase.get();` inside the `get()` I check `if(instance==null)` and then initialise it using the public accessible `Application` object.

If you keep in Android static reference of Activity, Fragment or View objects you will invariably run into memory issues. Those classes are BIG, they hold references to other big objects, they use a lot of memory and that's why the Framework have all the annoying `life-cycle` and `saveState`. So they can be destroyed when memory is needed and re-built when they're back on screen.

**2nd part: Android way**

in Android is not very advisable to just keep references of objects on `public static` because those will stay in memory forever, and a mobile phone is not like a webserver with terabytes of RAM. The whole Android Framework have a very well documented and stablished structure of passing and saving values (Strings, int, etc) via `Bundle` objects. Those bundles you can pass to activity via `Intent`, or to Fragments via `setArguments(Bundle)` and they can be used to save current state using `onSavedInstanceState` methods. And those are the advisable way of doing stuff the Android way. And it also helps promote class separation and even thou might sound like a lot of work for small projects, for bigger projects it's one of the ways to keep the structure and organisation.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. But what do you mean by "public static will stay in memory forever"? Are they yet in memory when the app is closed?? And if the app is opened again will there be new instances of these variables?

Comment: sorry, maybe I phrase it wrongly. What I meant is, they will stay in memory for as long as the JavaVirtualMachine (JVM) is running. Remember that "JVM is still running" is different than "activity is on the foreground"

Comment: That does not really answer the question. If 1 Application == 1 JVM then static or singleton are exactly the same thing. Or is there something else ?

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html:

> An alternate way to make data accessible across Activities/Services is to use public static fields and/or methods. You can access these static fields from any other class in your application.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.

So it looks to me like using static variables is perfectly valid.